# "No password hashes loaded" for JTR, for $apr1$ hash in single mode

Tags: linux, passwords, kali-linux

I'm trying to crack a hash for a CTF, which came from a .htpasswd file, and is stored as a $apr1$ hash. When I try and run John on the following file, stored as `hash.txt`, I get the "No password hashes loaded" message.

My `hash.txt` file:

```
vdaisley:$apr1$1ONUB/S2$58eeNVirnRDB5zAIbIxTYO0
```

My command:

```
john --single hash.txt
```

PS: I'm root, so it's probably not a perms problem.